# Django syncdb craps out on Python 2.6 - to_stored_data()?

Tags: python, mysql, django

My app works great locally on Python 2.7.2, but trying to deploy it on a shared host with Python 2.6.8 results in the following message when calling `syncdb`:

```
TypeError: to_stored_data() takes exactly 3 non-keyword arguments (2 given)
```

[Full traceback](http://pastebin.com/rYXdDeZk)

I haven't managed to find mentions of to_stored_data() in Django's codebase, or in Nullege. I have another Django site running without problem on the same machine, in a separate virtualenv. Any idea what this can be?

Comment: It looks like `to_stored_data` must be a signal handler connected to `pre_save`. Is it possible you've defined it yourself, or a third party app you're using has? `to_stored_data` is not in the django or South codebase.

Comment: Use [`grin`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grin) or grep to recursively search your project and virtualenv for instances of `to_stored_data`.

Comment: It's also possible that your shared hosting provider has patched a `to_stored_data` `pre_save` signal handler into the django version that you're using (if you didn't install it yourself).

Comment: That's exactly what it was - a pre-save handler I had implemented earlier today in response to an old TODO note. I'm not really sure what it really does, so I guess I just forgot about it. I'm an idiot. Feel free to post that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your broken `to_stored_data` `pre_save` signal handler.  =)